# Passing Pug variables from child template for use in parent template block

Tags: html, gulp, pug, template-engine

I'm working on a project that utilizes the Pug template engine. All my Pug files (layout.pug, head.pug, index.pug, etc.) are stored within a folder named pug. In my layout.pug file, I've established the foundational structure of my HTML document. My aim is to include the head.pug file to dynamically set the page title and canonical URL.

However, I've encountered an issue where the head.pug file is not being detected or applied during the rendering process. I've meticulously reviewed the file locations, syntax, and indentation, yet the problem persists.

What are some troubleshooting steps I can take to resolve this issue?

here is the code:

**1) head.pug**

```
meta(charset="UTF-8")
meta(name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0")
block title
 title #{pageTitle}
block description
 meta(name="description" content="#{pageDescription}")
block canonical
 link(rel="canonical" href="#{canonicalURL}")enter code here
```

**2) Layout.pug**

```
doctype HTML
html(lang="en")
 block head
  include head.pug
 body
   include navbar.pug
   block content
   include footer.pug
```

**3)  index.pug**

```
extends layout

block head
    include head.pug
        block title
            - var pageTitle = "My Website"
        block description
            - var description = "This is my official website"
        block canonical
            - var canonicalURL = "https://adityasutar.com/"

block content
    h1 Hello
```

Meta tags are not detected in the browsers

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things wrong with the code:

1. `include` declarations can't have things indented beneath them.
2. A `block` in a child template will *replace* the content of a `block` with the same name in a parent template
3. There's no `<head>` element defined (note that naming a block "head" doesn't automatically render a `<head>` element)
4. [Attribute interpolation syntax in the form `(attr="#{variable}")` doesn't work in Pug anymore](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html#attribute-interpolation)

A better way to achieve what you're trying to do would be as follows:

- **layout.pug**

  ```js
  doctype html
  html(lang='en')
    head
      block head
        include head.pug
    body
      include navbar.pug
      block content
      include footer.pug
  ```
- **head.pug**: *Note the updated interpolation syntax for attributes.*

  ```js
  meta(charset='UTF-8')
  meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
  title #{pageTitle}
  meta(name='description', content= pageDescription)
  link(rel='canonical', href= canonicalURL)
  ```
- **index.pug**: *Note the use of `prepend` instead of `block` here. This will put this block's content before any content within the corresponding block in the parent template, instead of replacing it. A separate block for each variable isn't necessary either.*

  ```js
  extends layout.pug

  prepend head
    - const pageTitle = "My Website"
    - const description = "This is my official website"
    - const canonicalURL = "https://example.com/"

  append content
    h1 Hello
  ```